# Google map works in localhost but not in published IIS but map in <iframe> works at both place

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

If I am asking a bad question please tell me I will remove this.

I created a page to show google map in my MVC project in two ways.

**Way 1:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

<div id="map" style="width:600px; height:500px"></div>

<script>
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(******, *******);
        var options = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: '******'
        });
        marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png');
       }
    initialize();

</script>
```

This code worked perfectly in my `localhost` but didn't show the map when in published to IIS. It give a blank space there.

**Way 2:**

I used

```
<iframe src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=
&amp;*************output=embed"></iframe>
```

this is working fine at localhost and published website on IIS.

What is the difference between both ways and why the map is not showing in the published website by the way1.

Comment: Try $j(document).ready(function(){ initialize(); });

Comment: @pszaba the first code is working in localhost only issue in server published..second code works at both side..

Comment: Is your IIS whitelisted i.e in "allowed referrer" list in developer console?

Comment: @KayAnn if it is not done can i deploy my project.Only issue is with the google map..but if i use iframe it is also working..

Comment: You can use iframe but keep in mind that you might not get all the maps API functionality you want with iframe. Also, its pretty simple to whitelist server in Google's Developer Console. Either ways be mindful of terms of services.

Comment: @KayAnn thanks for the reply..i didnt understand "whitelist server inGoogle Developer console"..how to do that..if I do so can show the map with out iframe

Answer (score 1):

Go to: https://console.developers.google.com.
Go to the respective project.
On the left you will see APIs & auth (drop down).
Go to Credentials. You will have API keys there. Go to Google Maps API (or any Google API for that matter). Click on "Edit allowed referrers" and add your domain(s) there.
If you have different server hosting different domain(s), Click on generate key (if you don't already have one) and get a Server key. Then click "edit allowed IP". 
That's whitelisting.